# Creating a bouncing ball in a box using objects, not working

Tags: javascript

i'm fairly new to javascript and am trying to do a task in which a ball bounces around a box/canvas. I managed to do this once but am now recreating it using objects, i'm getting no errors but it is not working and i'm honestly not sure what the issue is. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great thank you. The canvas draws but no ball.

```
<canvas id="sCanvas" width="550" height="550" style="border: solid">   </canvas>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

    //variables
    var c = document.getElementById("sCanvas");
    var ctx = sCanvas.getContext("2d");
    var cHeight = sCanvas.height;
    var cWidth = sCanvas.width;


    //object


    //create the sphere object
    class Sphere {
        constructor(aRadius){
            //add properties to object
            this.radius = (aRadius || 15); //if paramater not set then make 15
            this.colour = "green"//"hsl"( + 360 * Math.random() + ",50%,50%");
                 //create propertes for xPos, yPos, speedX, speedY
            //and assign sensible values to them either
            //hard coded or random numbers
            //don't forget to use the format .this as above
            this.xPos = 30;
            this.yPos = 30;
            this.speedX = 2;
            this.speedY = 5;

        }

        drawMe(){
            //method to draw itself
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(this.xPos, this.Ypos, this.radius, 0, Math.PI *2, true);
            ctx.fillStyle = this.colour;
            ctx.fill();
        }

        //method to move itself
        moveMe(){
            this.yPos += this.speedY;
            this.xPos += this.speedX;

            if (this.yPos > 540){
                //statement
                this.speedY =- this.speedY
            }

            else if (this.yPos < 10){
                //statement
                this.speedY =- this.speedY
            }

            if (this.xPos > 540){
                //statement
                this.speedX =- this.speedX
            }

            else if (this.xPos < 10){
                //statement
                this.speedX =- this.speedX
            }
        }
    }


//create a new instance if sphere - called ball
    var ball = new Sphere();
    //assign a 'new' instance of 'sphere()' here.

    //redraw the screen each time to create animation
        function render(){
            //recall render() using requestAnimationFrame API
            requestAnimationFrame(render);
            //clear canvas
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, cWidth, cHeight);
            //call the drawME method of the ball object
            ball.drawMe();
            //call the moveMe method of the ball object
            ball.moveMe();


        }

     render(); //set the animation and drawing on canvas going


</script> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your drawMe() function for ctx.arc() you put this.Ypos instead of this.yPos

One change you might want to make is to consider the size of the ball in your moveMe() method instead of hard-coding the numbers. I say this because you made the ball radius a variable size in your constructor.

If you change the ball radius to say 35 then part of it will go beyond the dimensions of the box when it hits the wall.

~Pat

Comment: ahh thank you, I knew it was going to be some silly mistake! Sorry if this was a waste of a time question! :)

Comment: Not a waste of time at all. I have had many of these typos over the decades.